# How to join an iterable in python (string join)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have looked other posts with similar problem.

this is my code:

```
def fit_replace(text):
    text = np.array(text)
    text = ' '.join(text)
    return text

df['REPLACE'] = df['ISI'].apply(fit_replace)
df.head(5)
```

this is the list in **text**:

```
[['ini', 'juga', 'saya', 'sambil', 'disambi', 'kerja', 'masih', 'belajar',...
```

the error:

```
    <ipython-input-101-15e80ecfee7e> in fit_replace(text)
      1 def fit_replace(text):
      2     text = np.array(text)
----> 3     text = ' '.join(text)
      4     return text
      5 

TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `text` into an iterable first.

For example:

```py
' '.join(list(text))
```

Comment: This makes no sense. `list` itself requires an iterable to construct it. The first step in the implementation of `str.join` is to convert any input that is not already a `tuple` or `list` to a `list` in the same way the `list` constructor does. Definitionally, if `' '.join(list(text))` works, so does `' '.join(text)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
df['REPLACE'] = df['ISI'].apply(''.join)
```

Will save you the hassle of defining a separate function, converting ad applying.

Comment: If the above works, the simpler solution would be `df['REPLACE'] = df['ISI'].apply(''.join)`. You don't need a `lambda` taking one argument and passing it to another function taking one argument, when that other function already takes one argument and does exactly what you want. Similarly, the OP's original code should have just been `df['REPLACE'] = df['ISI'].apply(fit_replace)`; you have a one-arg function that does what you want, stop wrapping it in another `lambda` for no reason.

Comment: True! It actually does the job. Will add that